# Linq for a list of lists

Tags: c#, linq

```
class Bar
{
   public DateTime Time { get; set; }
   public double Price { get; set; }
}

class Instrument
{
   public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public Instrument(string name, string path) { 
      // set the Bars list here reading from files
   }
}
```

Here are two simplified versions of my classes. I'm creating a custom backtesting platform for currencies. The current problem is to chop off bars where I don't have price data on every instrument.

I read prices from an XML file.

```
var xlinqBarLists = xlinqInstruments.Select(i => i.Bars);
```

which is basically

```
List<List<Bar>> xlinqBarLists
```

What I want to do is loop through each individual list, find the latest start date and the earliest end date, then lop off all bars outside of that time window. My hacked together code is

```
var xlinqInstruments = root.Elements("instrument").Select( a => 
   new Instrument( a.Element("name").Value, a.Element("path").Value ) );    

var xlinqBarLists = xlinqInstruments.Select(i => i.Bars);

DateTime latestStartDate = DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime earliestEndDate = DateTime.MaxValue;

foreach (List<Bar> bars in xlinqBarLists)
{
   if (bars.Min(b => b.Time) > latestStartDate)
      latestStartDate = bars.Min(b => b.Time);

   if (bars.Max(b => b.Time) < earliestEndDate)
       earliestEndDate = bars.Max(b => b.Time);
 }

foreach (List<Bar> barList in xlinqBarLists)
{
   var timeWindowBars = from bar in barList
                  where bar.Time >= latestStartDate && bar.Time <= earliestEndDate
                  select bar;

   // I need some way to overwrite the original Instrument.Bars property with timeWindowBars
   // Suggestions?
}
```

Can I do this more quickly and efficiently by skipping the foreach loops?

Comment: This should belong to code review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are you wanting to set the `Bars` property of each instrument to a `List<Bar>` containing only those objects that fall within the minimum end date and maximum start date across *all* `Bar` objects (including those present on other `Instrument`s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For latest start date and earliest end date you can use

```
DateTime latestStartDate = xlinqInstruments.Max(i => i.Bars.Min(bar => bar.Time));
DateTime earliestEndDate = xlinqInstruments.Min(i => i.Bars.Max(bar => bar.Time));
```

And for the last part maybe you would like to add a parameterless constructor for ´Instrument´ and then

```
var result = xlinqInstruments
                 .Select(i=>new Instrument()
                                    {
                                       Name = i.Name, 
                                       Bars = i.Bars.Where(bar => bar.Time >= latestStartDate 
                                                               && bar.Time <=earliestEndDate)
                                                    .ToList()
                                    });
```

Comment: It works brilliantly. Thanks for such an elegantly simple solution. I knew all those loops were making my life unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer if [my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713797/linq-for-a-list-of-lists#comment43840185_27713797), (which I've copy/pasted below) turns out to be the case.

> Are you wanting to set the Bars property of each instrument to a
>   List containing only those objects that fall within the minimum
>   end date and maximum start date across all Bar objects (including
>   those present on other Instruments)?

```
// Get the value of the earliest Bar.Time on each Instrument, and select the most recent of those.
DateTime latestStartDate = xlinqInstruments.Max(instrument => instrument.Bars.Min(bar => bar.Time));

// Get the value of the latest Bar.Time on each Instrument, and select the earliest of those.
DateTime earliestEndDate = xlinqInstruments.Min(instrument => instrument.Bars.Max(bar => bar.Time));

// Overwrite the Bars collection of each instrument with its contents truncated appropriately.
// I'd suggest doing this with a foreach loop as opposed to what I've provided below, but that's just me.
xlinqInstruments.ForEach(instrument => 
{
    instrument.Bars = instrument.Bars.Where(obj => obj.Time >= latestStartDate && obj.Time <= earliestEndDate).ToList();
});
```

It may be worth nothing that the [ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method requires you to call `.ToList()` on the `xlinqInstruments` collection first.  In my code, I assume the collection has already been materialized to `List<Instrument>`

You may also be interested in linq's [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534336%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method.

> **Enumerable.SelectMany Method (IEnumerable, Func>)**
>
> Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable and flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence.

Comment: Thanks Joshua for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score -1):

Call `ToList` before assigning to `xlinqBarLists`:

```
var xlinqBarLists = xlinqInstruments.Select(i => i.Bars).ToList();
```

Otherwise you're parsing the same XML over and over again.

You should most likely call `ToList` when creating `xlinqInstruments` as well, if you want to update them later.